# Почему venv в Linux не видит библиотеки Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, virtualenv

Писал программу на Windows. Потом перешёл на Linux, запустил виртуальное окружение и все ок, но Python не может найти библиотеки из виртуального окружения. Что делать?

Comment: Виртуальное окружение вы просто скопировали из Windows или настроили с нуля для Linux?

Comment: Я создал новую виртуалку в Linux, а с Windows просто перенёс библиотеки. Но почему-то обращение идёт к библиотекам системы, а не виртуалки

Comment: Попробуйте /<app_dir>/venv/bin/python /<app_dir>/app.py

Comment: @svmitin, спасибо) Теперь осталось только проблемы с библиотекой PIL решить и всё

Comment: Сталкивался с такой задачей. Если мне не изменяет память, библиотека PIL устарела и вместо нее можно установить Pillow. В свое время решил вроде бы так

Comment: @svmitin, Я как раз через Pillow и устанавливал. Там проблема в файле __init__ библиотеки Pillow. Там какой-то импорт не получается.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Библиотеки с Виндовс версии не совместимы с Линукс и наоборот. Не все, но ощутимая их часть. Используйте `pip freeze` для сохранения списка и `pip install -r requirements.txt` для установки их по списку в другой системе.